# How do I stop being seen as a rookie with something that I am quite knowledgeable in? And treated as such?

Tags: professionalism, career-development, colleagues, productivity

I have been working in an agile environment for the past year and a half (PHP, Java). Before that I was an apprentice with the company I work for, for a long while where I learnt how to make websites (basic html, css)...

But since then I've also spent a lot of my personal time (during non-work hours) reading various blogs, writing nifty functions in js, learning frameworks such as angular, libraries such as D3, and even writing my own version of jQuery (personal use). I've also recently started freelancing in my spare time for some extra cash.

Safe to say, I feel like while I know that I do not know as much as the seniors, I feel like I know enough of at least Javascript and CSS to not be lectured over simple things like defining a name space. But with one developer who is a senior, he constantly goes on and on about defining a namespace (of which I do every time), and extremely simple things like event handling etc. I feel like he's patronising me, and I find it very embarrassing.

Well a few days ago, I was writing inline javascript because I find it a lot easier to debug when mixing between a programming language and javascript, i.e. using values from the programming language in javascript. I then change this before it goes live with very little hassle, and since I was the only developer working on this I saw no problem doing this. Well he practically shouted at me over it saying "ALWAYS put this and that in a separate script file" and I told him I know this, I always have done aside from during the initial stage of development.

I just don't know how to handle it, while it may not be best practice to do it like that, and I didn't have all of the code outside of the js file, only the parts that were using values from the programming language.

He is a nice guy, he's not the kind of guy to say something spiteful and he's always helpful if I don't know something. I don't believe he does this as a way of patronising me, but as I say, it's extremely embarrassing because he speaks loudly in an open office plan and I find it quite insulting most of the time, just because of the sheer amount of time I spend working 14-15 hours a day some days (this job + freelancing/coding for fun).

Comment: There's a *lot* of similar questions with good answers on this site. Can you try browsing them a bit and see which fits your situation best? If none do then please clarify why not.

Comment: Time. Demonstrate your competence. Unfortunately that means not taking shortcuts in production code, even when they are harmless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, being the "new guy" is going to be like that for a while. Often times it takes switching jobs before you work with people who won't treat you like that - who don't remember you being the guy fresh out of school, in other words.

In the mean time you may wish to:

1. Stop taking things quite so personally. No need to be embarrassed. Explain - calmly - that you understand/know what he's talking about.
2. Speak to him and explain that while you greatly appreciate his help you do not appreciate being spoken to in that tone of voice.

You don't want to insult him, or to end up dealing with this situation at a managerial level (you really, really don't).

Comment: This rings with a similar tone to how its easier to advance your salary by job hopping every 18-36 months over staying with one company, at least in high tech.